# Is there some way to measure number of items read per item in the Content Editor

Tags: content-editor, templates, performance-optimization, performance

I'm wondering if there is any diagnostic tool, or technique which can be used to work out how many items are read from the DB for each item loaded in the content editor. I'm thinking of a Content Editor equivalent of the rendering statistics admin page. I know I could look at all inherited templates and look at any fields which are link fields or TreeList fields (or similar) and perhaps figure out how many queries/requests there are, but it would be pretty tedious.

My end goal is to quantitatively measure the benefit of changing certain field types from e.g. TreeList to TreeListEx to see how this will affect Content Editor performance.

Comment: we can check on Debug option in Experience Editor for Profiling.

Comment: @TrilokGiri this only works for profiling the front-end renderings. What I'm interested in is the performance impact of templates within the Content Editor i.e. if an item uses a template with 300 fields, how does this impact the DB in terms of the number of items read each time that item is selected in the CE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried that but maybe adding your own processors at the beginning and at the end of `<getContentEditorFields>` pipeline would do the trick?

And then using

```
Sitecore.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.DataCount.DataItemsAccessed.Value
```

to get the number of items read - you can store the initial value in `Sitecore.Context.Items` cache as it is a per-request cache, and then compare it with the value at the end of pipeline.